# flutter build failed Short read of DER length

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I dont know today i try to build an update but this error occur nothing change in signing keys etc please help resolving this

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\dance>flutter build appbundle --no-sound-null-safety

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key Godatu from store "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\dance\android\keystore\godatu_release.jks": Short read of DER length

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        54.5s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\dance>
```

Comment: I think there is an error while you have generated the certificate. Try generating the certificate once again and then import it

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your certificate file is not in the expected format.

Below is the example

> If the certificate is provided in Base64 encoding, it must be bounded
> at the beginning by -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----, and must be bounded
> at the end by -----END CERTIFICATE-----